# How can handle AlertDialogFragment events inside Fragment that created it?

Tags: android, android-fragments

For dialogs fragments UI [google recommends](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentAlertDialog.html) to extend DialogFragment. However in provided sample it handle alert inside activity, but I need to do it inside fragment that invoke dialog. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure that there are numerous ways but I pass a message `Handler` as a parameter to the constructor of my `DialogFragment`.

The message handler is a member of my fragment and in its `handleMessage` method I simply process messages that are sent from within the click events of my `DialogFragment`.

My message handler has a reference to my fragment so I can simply call onto whatever fragment methods I want.